# how does ambari use zookeeper to synchronize cluster configuration files in detail

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ambari, hdp

how does ambari use zookeeper to synchronize cluster configuration files in detail? I cannot search any doc about this, is there any example, all I can get is about how to use zookeeper to achieve HA in HDFS and HBase. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ambari does not need ZK to work. It only configures HDFS and HBase to use it.
See these [HDFS](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_hadoop-high-availability/content/ch_HA-NameNode.html) and [HBase](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_hadoop-high-availability/content/ha-hbase-intro.html) docs